# Explaination of Isolation Forest Algorithm Source Code

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was going through the source code for Isolation Forest Algorithm in sci-kit module. The overall structure of the model is:

```
read data set
train test split of data
train the data on model
fit the model
test other set of data on the model
predict anomalies
```

The source code is available in GitHub. In the source code there is a file called iforest.py (path: sklearn > ensemble > iforest.py )
In that file there is a function called score_samples which calculates the anomaly score for each data-point in the data-set.
The code looks somewhat like this :

```
def score_samples(self, X):

    n_samples = X.shape[0]
    n_samples_leaf = numpy.zeros((n_samples, self.n_estimators), order="f")
    depths = numpy.zeros((n_samples, self.n_estimators), order="f")
    if self._max_features == X.shape[1]:
        subsample_features = False
    else:
        subsample_features = True

    for i, (tree, features) in enumerate(zip(self.estimators_ self.estimators_features_)):                                     
        if subsample_features:
            X_subset = X[:, features]
        else:
            X_subset = X
        leaves_index = tree.apply(X_subset)
        node_indicator = tree.decision_path(X_subset)
        n_samples_leaf[:, i] = tree.tree_.n_node_samples[leaves_index]
        depths[:, i] = numpy.ravel(node_indicator.sum(axis=1))
        depths[:, i] -= 1

    depths += _average_path_length(n_samples_leaf)

    scores = 2 ** (-depths.mean(axis=1) / _average_path_length(
        self.max_samples_))

    # Take the opposite of the scores as bigger is better (here less
    # abnormal)
    return -scores
```

I cannot understand what is happening in the for loop. Can someone please help me out with this.